# ordinary differential equations exercise

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I'd like to resolve the ode $x'(t)=\cos(\ln(1+x(t)^2))$, given the inicial value $x(0)=1$, for t belonging to the interval [0,pi]. By separated variables method I get t equal to the primitive of the function $\sec(\ln(1+x^2))dx$, that I don't know how to calculate. Thank you very much in advanced!!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives up, so I don't think you will find an elementary solution. This problem would be pretty easy numerically speaking, though, because $x$ will just slowly increase toward $(e^{\pi/2}-1)^{1/2} \approx 1.95$.

Comment: You could try a solution based on matching power series;  this should work because the actual solution never exceeds $2$ (so you never leave the radius of convergence of the $\ln$ series).

Answer (score 0):

$x'(t)=\cos(\ln(1+x(t)^2))$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\cos(\ln(1+x^2))$

$dt=\sec(\ln(1+x^2))~dx$

$\int_0^tdt=\int_1^x\sec(\ln(1+x^2))~dx$

$[t]_0^t=\int_1^x\sec(\ln(1+x^2))~dx$

$t=\int_1^x\sec(\ln(1+x^2))~dx$